# What do Skarner's Crystals do in patch 5.16?

Tags: league-of-legends

When playing Skarner in the new patch there are crystals all over the jungle which can be captured by him, or reset by the enemy, what do the crystals do for the team Skarner is on, and do the crystals do anything for the opposite team?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [Patchnotes](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-516-notes):

> NEW Passive - Crystal Spires
>   Skarner's presence causes crystals to spawn in set locations around the map. Crystals can be captured by either team by standing on top of them. Capturing a crystal prevents them from being captured by the opposing team for 15 seconds.
>
> While near active crystals, Skarner gains 70 - 120 Movement Speed (66 + 4 / 3 / 2 per champion level), 43~164% (34 + 9 / 7 / 5 per champion level) Attack Speed, and restores 2% of his maximum Mana per second.

So if the enemy team captures a crystal, it just means you can't get the buff there and you can't capture the crystal for 15 seconds. Nothing else from what i have seen.

For yourself, it is a buffzone. Also, if you capture the crystal on your own, you get 15 gold from it. If more than one champ participated in the capturing, 30 gold are split among the people who captured it.

Comment: I played an ARAM with skarner the other day and I think I gained a small amount of gold for capturing the crystals as well. Does this apply to everyone?

Comment: @clcto: I am guessing this is due to the ARAM rules, where it counts as a special unit and you gain gold from it, but this is pure speculation from my side...

Comment: It does grant some gold for capturing it on SR as well.